# Select count and group by from two tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables `Affaire(ID, Obj, ID_TA ...)` and `TypeAffaire(ID_TA, Label)`, i want to count number of each `ID_TA` in Affaire and show the `label` instead if `ID_TA`, I tried this but it doesnt work :

```
SELECT  A.ID_TA
    ,T.Label
    ,count(*) AS TotalAmount
FROM    Affaire AS A
LEFT JOIN TypeAffaire AS T ON T.ID_TA = A.TA
GROUP BY A.ID_TA;
```

it says that label can't be found

Comment: I found it, the error is because label is included in the SELECT list, but is not included in a GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `T.Label` as well. All non-aggegated fields in the `select` clause, must also be in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Add T.Label in `Group By`

Try this

```
SELECT  A.ID_TA
    ,T.Label
    ,count(*) AS TotalAmount
FROM    Affaire AS A
LEFT JOIN TypeAffaire AS T ON T.ID_TA = A.TA
GROUP BY A.ID_TA,T.Label;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Insert T.Label in the group by clause, and correct the `ON T.ID_TA = A.TA in to ON T.ID_TA = A.ID_TA`

```
SELECT  A.ID_TA ,T.Label ,count(*) AS TotalAmount
FROM  Affaire AS A
LEFT JOIN TypeAffaire AS T ON T.ID_TA = A.ID_TA
GROUP BY A.ID_TA, T.Label;
```